# Replacement for Readfile() for remote file that won't consume lots of memory?

Tags: php, header

I've been using Xsendfile module for a while, but that was for when I was storing files on my local computer. It worked great. I now store files on a remote server and need to have the file change the name on download. I set up this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$quote{$name3}$quote");
readfile("http://www.example.com/file.txt");
```

That works great (minus the fact I need add in contentsize header and content-type, but I'll change that after this is fixed). The problem is it consumes lots of memory. I could probably download 4-5 at a time max.

Can XSendFile be used on remote urls? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: how much memory? how are you testing? how much do you have? -and i would give curl a try.

Comment: @Dagon I have a vps and its around 6GB

Answer (score 1):

> Can XSendFile be used on remote urls?

No. It depends on the fact that the file is available locally.

> Is there a better way to go about this?

Set up a script (perhaps using XSendFile) on the remote server to send the appropriate filenames.

Comment: Is there a way to setup something like that on S3? I know you can make your S3 a webserver... not sure how to go about that